# MxParser and nuget

Tags: c#

I have a project in ASP .NET CORE 2.1. In it I use my dll written in .NET STANDARD 2.0, which uses mxparser Nuget.

When I run the project I'm getting message:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MathParser.org-mXparser.Stand20, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0fbab7add73ed6e2'.

In assets.json file there is a link to mxparser to .NET CORE lib, but my dll must use .NET STANDARD lib.

https://github.com/holeksas/MxParserProblem

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for help

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? That would make it a lot easier to help you. (I suspect you should be able to reproduce the problem with a .NET Core 2.1 console app rather than ASP.NET Core as well.)

Comment: No problem. This is very easy to check. https://github.com/holeksas/MxParserProblem

Comment: Having the github repo is good; including the code in the question as text would be better.

Comment: Urgh. Fundamentally it looks like the package is badly created. All the DLLs should have the same name (but in separate lib directories). The way it's packaged at the moment simply isn't how NuGet packages are expected to work :(

Comment: (Admittedly the namespace suggests the author doesn't care too much about following platform conventions in general...) Is there any possibility of changing your library to target netcoreapp2.1 instead of netstandard2.0? (I accept it may very well not be possible.)

Comment: I prefer NetStandard in library because, it can be used in Azure Function v2 on Microsoft azure, and there is NetStandard 2.0.

Comment: I completely agree that netstandard would be *preferable* - but if you absolutely need to use this library (and don't have the time/inclination to repackage it yourself) I suspect it's the only option. I would strongly recommend adding an issue explaining to the library author that their package is fundamentally broken though. (Chances are they don't really need *nearly* as many targets as they've got at the moment, either.)

Comment: It seems there is a new version (from yesterday) were dll names were fixed. Should work as you suggested. I am using mXparser quite often (mainly scientific projects) both in java and c#. It does not follow c# naming conventions as the .net version is 1-1 port from java.

Comment: Yes, problem is fixed in MxParser version 4.2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is fixed in MxParser version 4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

'mxparser.netstandard20.dll' this is a bit strange dll name as the mXparser nuget package contains 'MathParser.org-mXparser.Stand20.dll'

It looks like manually created reference...

Best regards

Comment: Yes, I know the name is 'MathParser.org-mXparser.Stand20.dll' . I don't set manual references. This name is only an example.